# Perturbing the Harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, perturbation-theory

Assume that a quantum harmonic oscillator is described by the Hamiltonian,
\begin{equation}
H=H_0+\lambda q^2
\end{equation}
where,
\begin{equation}
H_0=\frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2q^2
\end{equation}
If $|\Psi_0⟩$ is the ground state of $H$, it can always be written as a linear combination of the eigenstates of $H_0$ ({$|n⟩$}), 
\begin{equation}
|\Psi_0⟩=\sum_{n}c_n|n⟩
\end{equation}
What are the values of $c_n$?

Comment: Just to check: you really mean $\lambda q^2$ not some other power like $q^4$?

Comment: Yes it's $\lambda q^2$.

Comment: As written this question appears off-topic. Do you have a conceptual question? We don't provide solutions to standard exercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a homework type problem, I'll try to not give the entire solution, but this is how I'd do it:

It should not have escaped your attention that both $H$ and $H_0$ are very similar in their *forms*, in that both of them have the same dependence on $p$ and $q$. The difference, you'll notice, is only in the pre-factor of $q$.

Show that you can write $H$ as a harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian, but with a *different* frequency (call it $\omega^\prime$) which depends on $\lambda$. (As a test, you could show that when $\lambda=0$, $\omega = \omega^\prime$.)

Now, since you have written $H$ as a harmonic oscillator with frequency $\omega^\prime$, you can immediate write out its normalised ground state wavefunction, $\Psi_0(x)$. All that's left is to decompose this wavefunction in terms of the energy eigenbasis of $H_0$ (let's call these functions $\psi_n^0(x)$), which you can do by using the orthogonality property of these eigenfunctions, i.e.

$$c_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Psi_0^*(x) \psi_n^0(x)\text{d} x.$$

I admit this isn't very elegant as you'd need the general form of the Harmonic Oscillator wavefunctions (which I doubt many people could remember offhand without looking at a book), but it's not obvious to me how else this could be done. I'm actually curious to know if there's a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are completely sure that your perturbed Hamiltonian is correctly written you don't need to do anything fancy, just consider

$$
V(q) = (\frac{1}{2}mw^2 + \lambda)q,
$$

solve this new problem, and try to related how this ground state compare to the standard case.